# Serial Port Communication Issue in C Code on Linux

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, pyserial, termios

I am facing an issue with serial port communication in a C program on Linux. The scenario is as follows:

After booting my Linux system, I run a C program that reads data from a serial port. However, it seems that the serial port is not receiving data.

Interestingly, when I run a Python script that opens and closes the serial port before running the C program, everything works as expected. The C program starts receiving data from the serial port.

I have shared the relevant parts of my C code and the Python script below:

C Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

volatile sig_atomic_t stop_flag = 0;

void handle_signal(int signum)
{
    printf("Caught signal %d\n", signum);
    if (signum == SIGINT || signum == SIGTERM)
    {
        printf("Stopping...\n");
        stop_flag = 1;
        printf("Stopped\n");
    }
    printf("Exiting signal handler\n");
}

void cleanup(int serial_fd, FILE *outputFile)
{
    printf("Cleaning up...\n");
    close(serial_fd);
    fclose(outputFile);
    printf("Cleaned up\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    if (argc != 7)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <serial_port> <output_file> <baud_rate> <parity> <data_bits> <stop_bits>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const char *serialPortName = argv[1];
    const char *outputFileName = argv[2];
    int baudRate = atoi(argv[3]);
    char parity = argv[4][0];
    int dataBits = atoi(argv[5]);
    int stopBits = atoi(argv[6]);

    // Open the serial port
    int serial_fd = open(serialPortName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (serial_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening serial port");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Set serial port parameters
    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));
    if (tcgetattr(serial_fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error getting serial port attributes");
        cleanup(serial_fd, NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, baudRate);
    cfsetispeed(&tty, baudRate);

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;

    // Set parity
    if (parity == 'N')
    {
        tty.c_cflag &= ~PARODD; // No parity
    }
    else if (parity == 'E')
    {
        tty.c_cflag |= PARODD; // Even parity
    }
    else if (parity == 'O')
    {
        tty.c_cflag |= (PARENB | PARODD); // Odd parity
    }

    // Set data bits
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    if (dataBits == 8)
    {
        tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    }
    else if (dataBits == 7)
    {
        tty.c_cflag |= CS7;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of data bits\n");
        cleanup(serial_fd, NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Set stop bits
    if (stopBits == 1)
    {
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // 1 stop bit
    }
    else if (stopBits == 2)
    {
        tty.c_cflag |= CSTOPB; // 2 stop bits
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number of stop bits\n");
        cleanup(serial_fd, NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (tcsetattr(serial_fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error setting serial port attributes");
        cleanup(serial_fd, NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    if (access(outputFileName, F_OK) != -1)
    {
        // check for the file already exists, if yes, rename to filename_old_current_time
        char oldFileName[256];
        strcpy(oldFileName, outputFileName);
        strcat(oldFileName, "_old_");
        time_t now = time(NULL);
        struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
        char timeStr[256];
        strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr) - 1, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", t);
        strcat(oldFileName, timeStr);
        rename(outputFileName, oldFileName);
    }
    // Open the output file
    FILE *outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "wb");
    if (!outputFile)
    {
        perror("Error opening output file");
        cleanup(serial_fd, NULL);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Register signal handler for graceful termination
    signal(SIGINT, handle_signal);
    signal(SIGTERM, handle_signal);

    printf("Starting...\n");
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (!stop_flag)
    {
        ssize_t bytesRead = read(serial_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, outputFile);
            fflush(outputFile);
        } else if (bytesRead < 0) {
            perror("Error reading from serial port");
            cleanup(serial_fd, outputFile);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            // No data read            
        }
    }

    printf("Stopping...\n");

    // Cleanup and close resources before exiting
    cleanup(serial_fd, outputFile);

    // Reset signal handlers to default behavior
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGTERM, SIG_DFL);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```py
import serial
import time

port_name = "/dev/ttyXR0"
baud_rate = 2000000

serial_port = serial.Serial(port_name, baud_rate)

if serial_port:
    try:
        print("opened")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        serial_port.close()
```

I'm trying to understand why the serial port communication works after running the Python script. Are there any specific configurations or initializations in the Python script that might be affecting the behavior of the serial port when the C program is subsequently run?

I've already tried [list of things you've tried, e.g., removing O_NONBLOCK, introducing delays, etc.], but the issue persists.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Tip: avoid potential buffer overruns.  e.g. `strcpy(oldFileName, outputFileName); 
 strcat(oldFileName, "_old_"); ...` --> `snprintf(oldFileName, sizeof oldFileName, "%s%s%s', outputFileName, "_old_",  timeStr);`

Comment: Minor: -1 not needed in `strftime(timeStr, sizeof(timeStr) - 1, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", t);`

Comment: Since code is having trouble, makes sense to do more error checking like the return value of `rename()`, signal(),...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't read from serial port if not opened once with minicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138242/cant-read-from-serial-port-if-not-opened-once-with-minicom). Your termios configuration is incomplete and leaves canonical or noncanonical mode to chance. BTW Non-blocking mode is not advised; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680

Comment: Does it work with hardcoded serial port parameters? Parity configuration logic looks wierd. Run `stty < /dev/ttyXR0` after your C program and python program and compare configurations. Side note: don't use `printf()` in signal handlers and don't use `signal()` to setup handler.

Comment: You're trying to access a serial terminal that typically defaults to canonical mode, i.e. reading lines of ASCII text.  In your post you completely neglect to mention what kind of data you expect to receive. Your termios initialization only sets the UART line parameters; there is nothing to configure cooked or raw mode. Your code is simply incomplete, and therefore its behavior is susceptible to what is executed prior.