# Prevent canonical Mode from echoing special characters in C

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, termios, vt100

Is there a way to prevent canonical mode from echoing characters such as arrow keys by modifying the termios struct?

I've tried to play around with raw mode but I would need to rewrite a lot in order to make this bit of functionality work, that is already available in canonical mode

Comment: You are tagging this _shell_. Are you sure that you are refering here to POSIX shell? It's pretty unusual to use arrow keys when running an interactive POSIX shell, but if you really want to do it, have a look at `rlwrap`[https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap], i.e. start your shell with `rlwrap sh`.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `c` and `termios`?

Comment: ... alternatively, why is it tagged with `shell`?  The reference to the "termios struct" suggests that you are writing a C program.  Even if that program happened to be a shell, the question itself would not be in any way specific to shells.

Comment: You probably need to toggle the 'echo' bit — ECHO in the local modes.

Comment: It is tagged with shell because I figured it related to handling IO through shell and modifying that shell with termios. Thanks for pointing me towards rlwrap im going to check it out

Comment: the echo bit disables echo of all characters

Comment: @user1934428, it depends on what you mean by a POSIX shell, I guess.  Bash recognizes the arrow keys for history retrieval and command-line editing, for example, even when run as `/bin/sh`.  I'm pretty sure it's not alone in that.

Comment: @ElenaBogner, if you are in fact writing a C program, and `rlwrap` seems interesting to you, then it would probably be better for you to use the GNU readline library directly than via `rlwrap`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : Yes, but the question is tagged _shell_, not _bash_. We are not talking about bash here.

Comment: @ElenaBogner And if you cannot use GNU readline for licensing reasons, you can use the BSD-licensed Editline Library (libedit).

Comment: Bash was just an example, @user1934428.  Many other shells do the same.  I'm not sure where you would even find a 100% conforming POSIX shell, so I'm also not sure how to judge what is usual or unusual when running one, but nothing prevents such a shell from providing the behavior the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent canonical mode from echoing characters such as arrow keys by modifying the termios struct?

The [termios interfaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) provide a comparatively large number of flags for modulating echo behavior.  All have effect in canonical mode, and most of them *only* in that mode.  But none of them provide for suppressing echo of arbitrary characters.  They are all either general to all characters or specific to particular characters.  So **no**.

> I've tried to play around with raw mode but I would need to rewrite a lot in order to make this bit of functionality work, that is already available in canonical mode

No doubt you would.  Raw mode is not intended for interactive terminals.  At least, not for direct exposure to interactive users.

If the terminal driver does not by itself meet all your needs, and you do not want to write your own command-line editing code, then you should consider using a third-party library that does the job.  GNU readline (libreadline; GPL-licensed) or BSD-derived EditLine (libedit; BSD-licensed) would be candidates to consider.

Comment: This answer has a few errors. "*All have effect in canonical mode, and most of them only in that mode.*" - Misleading. The primary echo mode can be specified independently of canonical mode. "*Raw mode is not intended for interactive terminals*" - And yet several terminal emulation programs use (and leave) the serial terminal in a raw mode. E.G. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138242/cant-read-from-serial-port-if-not-opened-once-with-minicom/52142114#52142114

Comment: Feel free to write your own answer, @sawdust.  I disagree that anything you've mentioned constitutes an error in this answer or even is misleading.

Comment: @sawdust  Certainly the only one of the four POSIX-specified echo-modulation flags that has effect in non-canonical mode is the overall echo mode flag.  If any would, then surely that's the one that would be expected.  Only half of the four Linux-specific ones have effect in non-canonical mode. Five of eight counts as "most" in my book.  And in any case, the question is about things that *do* work in canonical mode, so the most salient point is that they all do.

Comment: As for raw mode, @sawdust, terminal emulation programs that operate the terminal driver in raw mode do not expose that directly to users, which is precisely what I said.  The whole point of a terminal emulation program is to moderate between a user and an underlying I/O device.  If such a program does not restore the original terminal mode when it exits then that speaks poorly for its implementation quality, but that does not imply that the resulting configuration is believed well suited for interactive use.